# Split in to Sentences and Wrap With Tags

Tags: javascript, regex, nlp

I'm trying to build a text fixing page for normalising text written in all capital letters, all lower case or an ungrammatical mixture of both.

What I'm currently trying to do is write a regular expression to find all full stops, question marks and line breaks, then split the string in to various strings containing all of the words up to and including each full stop.

Then I'm going to wrap them with `<span>` tags and use CSS `:first-letter` and `text-transform:capitalize;` to capitalise the first letter of each sentence.

The last stage will be writing a dictionary function to find user-specified words for capitalisation.

This question only concerns the part about writing a regex and splitting in to strings.

I've tried too many methods to post here, with varying results, but here's my current attempt:

```
for(var i=0; i < DoIt.length; i++){ 
    DoIt[i].onclick = function(){

        var offendingtext = input.value.toString();
        var keeplinebreaks = offendingtext.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
        var smalltext = keeplinebreaks.toLowerCase();
        //split at each character I specify
        var breakitup = smalltext.split(/[/.?\r\n]/g);

        breakitup.forEach(function(i){
            var i;
            console.log(i);
            var packagedtogo = document.createElement('span');
            packagedtogo.className = 'sentence';
            packagedtogo.innerHTML = breakitup[i];
            output.appendChild(packagedtogo);
            i++;
        });
    }
}
```

It was splitting at the right places before, but it was printing `undefined` in the output area between the tags. I've been at this for days, please could someone give me a hand.

**How can I split a string in to multiple string sentences, and then wrap each string with html tags?**

Comment: Why are you doing `var i` and `i++` inside a `forEach`? That seems to be the problem... `forEach(function(value, index){...})`

Comment: @elclanrs To be honest I got lost, really tired at the moment. Don't know how far to `Ctrl+Z` back to. As I said this is far from the first thing I've tried, if you want I'll rewrite the best working one I've managed, but it still isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex for the split is fine. Just forgot to escape a few characters:

```
var str = "SDFDSFDSF?sdf dsf sdfdsf. sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsf sdf."
str.split( (/[\.\?\r\n]/g))
//["SDFDSFDSF", "sdf dsf sdfdsf", " sdfdsfsdfdsfdsfdsfdsfsdfdsf sdf", ""]
```

Use for each iteration capabilities like this:

```
    breakitup.forEach(function(element){
        var packagedtogo = document.createElement('span');
        packagedtogo.className = 'sentence';
        packagedtogo.innerHTML = element;//breakitup is undefiend
        output.appendChild(packagedtogo);
        //No need to increase index
    });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, can you help with finding and splitting at each full stop, question mark and line break, please? That is the much harder part.

Comment: @Dominic it seems fine. You do have a problem here (/[/.?\r\n]/g) you are not escaping the dot and question mark. (/[\.\?\r\n]/g). see edit